# Intent service not stop explicitly

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-intentservice

I had created downloading task using intent service. which shows notification with progress bar with percentage.I'm using local broadcast manager to pass data while downloading.I also add one button to cancel download in notification but the problem is while i'm clicking on cancel Download it not stop Intent service. how can i stop intent service. Here i put my code of Intent service and also broadcast receiver to close service.

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
    public DownloadService() {
        super(DownloadService.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        InputStream input;
        OutputStream output;
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        intent1.setAction("com.demo.downloading");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return;
            }

            final int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte data[] = new byte[8192];
            long total = 0;
            int count, latestPercentDone;
            int percentDone = -1;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
              latestPercentDone = (int) (total * 100 / fileLength);
                if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
                    percentDone = latestPercentDone;
                    if (percentDone < 100) {
                        if (percentDone != 0) {
                            intent1.putExtra("progress", "" + percentDone);
                            intent1.putExtra("IsCancel", false);
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent1);
                        }
                    }
                    if (percentDone == 100) {
                        intent1.putExtra("progress", "" + 0);
                        intent1.putExtra("IsCancel", false);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent1);
                    }
                }
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                if (StaticFields.cancelDownload) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: Download Cancel");
                    this.stopSelf();
                }
            }
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            intent1.putExtra("progress", "" + (-1));
            intent1.putExtra("IsCancel", true);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent1);
            e.printStackTrace();
            is_all_download = false;
        }
    }
}
```

My broadcast receiver class
OnReceive method ()

```
if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (action.equals("notification_cancelled")) {
                    Global.cancelDownload = true;
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                    intent1.setAction("com.demo.downloading");
                    intent1.putExtra("IsCancel", true);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent1);
                }
            }
        }
```

LocalBroadcast manager receive method

```
boolean isCancel = intent.getBooleanExtra("IsCancel", false);
            if (isCancel) {
                Global.cancelDownload = true;
                mContext.stopService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Comment: actually i don't have any idea on Download manager and also i want to display progress in notification with cancel download button so...

Answer (score 1):

In an `IntentService`, `onHandleIntent()` is called on a worker (background) thread. When you call `stopService()`, this has no effect on the worker threads, as they will still run to completion. Calling `stopService()` on an `IntentService` makes no sense anyway, since an `IntentService` runs when it has work to do and stops itself when all of the work is finished.

Instead of calling `stopService()`, you need to set a flag in your `Service` that can be checked in the loop in your `onHandleIntent()` method. If the flag is set, you should abort further processing in your loop and end the worker thread yourself.

Comment: thank you for your answer but the problem is when i check in loop it makes app freeze don't know what problem occur.

Comment: and what about for multiple downloading ?

Comment: I don't understand your comments. Please post some code and indicate what the problem is.

Comment: I already put my code and in while loop i was check weather click on dismiss or not

Comment: In your loop, you call `stopSelf()`, but you do not exit the loop, so the loop continues to download. Calling `stopSelf()` is useless, you must end the `onHandleIntent()` method (by calling `return` or `break` or whatever).

Comment: Also, you set `Global.cancelDownload` to `true`, but then in your loop you check `StaticFields.cancelDownload` :-(

Comment: how can i download multiple files because when i click on another download it re download new file. and old file is terminated.

Comment: i don't see why you cannot download multiple files. Each should start a separate worker thread. using `IntentService`. I don't know why the "old file" should be terminated. Add logging and/or debug it.

Comment: OnDownloading start i'm displaying notification in my activity and update from intent service so when i click it may generate new notification ?

Comment: I don't know your architecture. It should be possible to have simultaneous downloads. If you are using notifications, you need to decide if you want to have one notification for all downloads, or one for each. You need to think about how to handle the cancellation of one or more downloads if you have simultaneous downloads. There are many things to consider. Also the uniqueness of PendingIntent request codes and notification IDs will have an effect. I can't write your code for you or solve all your problems. If you have something specific, please open a new question.

Comment: currently i put notification code in comment and put log inside loop but it display only first 100 not other ones